# Button to show and hide elements by ID only - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Currently my show and hide items button works perfectly. I have a JSON with multiple inputs, I want that when I click the button it only opens the input that I clicked on. My problem is that if I click on 1 element, the other IDs are shown.

Here is the code for better explanation:

```
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      show_info: false
    }
  }

  ...

  const ARTags    = this.state.nearbyPlaces.map((item) => {
      const imagen = item.imagen;
      const id = item.id;

      const showInfo = () => {
        this.setState({show_info: !this.state.show_info});
      };

      return (    
      ...

      <ViroImage 
        onClick={showInfo} 
        // onClick just for this id
        width={1.5} 
        height={1.5} 
        source={{uri: imagen}} 
        position={[0,-1.5,0]}
        style={ {borderRadius: 1, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#ffffff'}}

      />

      { this.state.show_info &&
        <ViroImage
          height={2}
          width={4}
          position={[coords.x, 5, coords.z]}
          placeholderSource={require("./res/qr/local_spinner.jpg")}
          source={{uri: imagen_1}} 
        />
      }
      ....
```

That's just a snippet of my code. That's the important part.

As you can see, I iterate through all the elements with "ARTags". The button changes state to hide and show. If I click they show and hide all at the same time.

I repeat: I only want to show and hide the ID of that button that I clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      show_info: false
    }
  }

  ...

  const ARTags    = this.state.nearbyPlaces.map((item) => {
      const imagen = item.imagen;
      const id = item.id;

      const showInfo = (itemid) => {
        // set state to item.id
        this.setState({show_info: itemid});
      };

      return (    
      ...

      <ViroImage 
        onClick={ () => showInfo(id) } {/* pass items id to showInfo */}
        // onClick just for this id
        key={id}
        width={1.5} 
        height={1.5} 
        source={{uri: imagen}} 
        position={[0,-1.5,0]}
        style={ {borderRadius: 1, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#ffffff'}}

      />

      { 
        // check state equals this item's id
        this.state.show_info === id &&
        <ViroImage
          key={`show${id}`}
          height={2}
          width={4}
          position={[coords.x, 5, coords.z]}
          placeholderSource={require("./res/qr/local_spinner.jpg")}
          source={{uri: imagen_1}} 
        />
      }
      ....
```

Comment: edited to add the `key={id}` and `key={\`show${id}\`}`. FYI, you should always add the key prop to elements generated in a loop like `map`

Comment: It works, but when I open one I can't close it again and I can't open the other. The state only changes once.

Comment: you may want to create an `ARTag` component with its own internal `show_info` state

Comment: Before I had **!this.state.show_info** to change the state from false to true and vice versa and thus show and hide. Now yes, only the information of the button that I indicate is shown, but I cannot hide it.

Comment: Note: if I click on one it is shown, if I click on the other the previous one is hidden and the new one is shown. I want that if I click on one it will be shown, if I click on it again it will be hidden.

Comment: `this.setState( (currentState) => ({ show_info:  currentState === itemid ? false : itemid }) )`

Comment: It remains the same, it does not hide when I click on the one that is already being shown. Remember that the conditional says: **{ this.state.show_info === id &&** Is anything else missing?

Comment: I already solved it with: **{ this.state.show_info_id === id && this.state.show_info &&** THANKS, @Alex.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).